# validating two columns in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i doing validation in my grades but it not working here my model for my grades

```
class Grade < ApplicationRecord
enum grade_type: %w(first_grading second_grading third_grading forth_grading)
#enum grade_type: [:first_grading, :second_grading, :third_grading, :forth_grading]

belongs_to :student_subject

validates :grade_type, uniqueness:{scope: [:student_subject_id, :score]}, presence: true
validates :status, :student_subject_id, presence: true

end
```

but when i input first grading with different score in wont validate

this is my desire output

---

(score: 85 student_subject_id: 2 grade_type: 0 status: test)
(score: 85 student_subject_id: 1 grade_type: 0 status: test)
(this is correct)

(score: 85 student_subject_id: 2 grade_type: 0 status: test)
(score: 83 student_subject_id: 1 grade_type: 0 status: test)
(this is correct)

Comment: Since you've setup a association you can use `student_subject` instead of `student_subject_id`

Comment: So a student can not have multiple grades with same `grade_type` and `score`? Is score really meant to be part of the uniqueness scope? 

If not use instead `uniqueness: { scope: :student_subject }` which means a student can only have 1 of each `grade_type`. 

Also could you clarify which test data is accurate and which isn't?

Comment: yes it work i put also the grade type i was really confuse and i'm new in rails